# Compare a SQL count result with previous result value - how many new records since my last select count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a script inserting new values on a table. When I `select count(*)` the results are shown. Is there a way to compare this value with the new one when I repeat the query?

Considering that the script is still inserting new values, I want to know how many new records since my last select count.

Comment: Whats the context for this? Are you just wanting to run this from SSMS manually while the insert is happening? Or something else?

Comment: Yes @DaleBurrell, exactly this, while the script is running, im on microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: And do you just want a single number since the last time you ran it? Or do you want a history?

Comment: yes, it could be a single number

Comment: You can always save a value, e.g. `declare @Count1 as Int = ( select Count(*) from Foo );` for use later. Aside: [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a handy way to get the number of rows affected by a statement, e.g. an `insert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily do this because each time you run your query (if running manually) it will reset any variables you have. There are 3 options I can think of:

1. Similar to Gordon's code, but you have to manually save the value each time you run it

```
declare @saved_count int = 0; -- THIS MUST BE MANUALLY UPDATED EACH TIME YOU RUN IT

-- Get the different since the last run
select count(*)-@saved_count
from MyTable;

-- Get the current value => manually copy to @saved_count above
select count(*)
from MyTable;
```

2. Store the value in more permanent storage as per Lukasz's answer (you can use a global temp table which will go once the connection is dropped which won't affect production).
3. You can run an automatic query as follows which keeps track of the current value and regularly prints out some details for you.

```
declare @CurrentCount int = 0, @LastCount int = 0;

while 1 = 1 begin
  select @CurrentCount = count(*)
  from MyTable;

  select getdate(), @CurrentCount - @LastCount;
  raiserror('Force a buffer flush',0,1) with nowait;

  set @LastCount = @CurrentCount;

  waitfor delay '00:00:10'; -- Wait 10s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could materialize it:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_stat(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), t DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(), cnt BIGINT);

INSERT INTO tab_stat(cnt)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tab_name;

SELECT *, cnt - LAG(cnt,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS diff
FROM tab_stat
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=58c122bcd52a603717631c1718c1b73e)**

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz, and sorry because i didn't include some informations: i'm in a production environment so im avoiding to create new temp tables. You know how to do this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot do this.  However, if your table has an identity column *you could remember it* and then do:

```
select count(*)
from t
where id > @saved_id;
```

You could do something similar with a creation date/time if that is available.

You would, of course, have to assign the maximum id (or create time) to a variable for this to work the next time.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon but didnt work, return "Must declare the scalar variable "@saved_id".